# Trying to solve issue with a dynamic reference that is causing a 1004 Error - Sort reference not valid

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem that I am sure will be very obvious to someone, but I am a bit too amateur to figure it out it seems. The problem is I am trying to use a string variable as a range reference but it keeps generating the 1004. Code

```
Sub reorder()
'
' reorder macro
'
Dim LR As Long
LR = 54572 'manually assigned last row value (in actual version it is assigned globally elswhere)
'
Dim thisRange As String
thisRange = "A2:H" & LR
'
MsgBox thisRange
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("C40-1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("C40-1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "A2:H54572"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("C40-1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:H54572")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

The code shown runs fine. MsgBox and sorting and all.
The problem is if I replace the absolute Range reference with "thisRange" variable the code fails.
E.g.

```
.SetRange Range(thisRange)
```

I'm confused

Comment: `Range("A2:H54572")` will by default refer to whatever sheet is active - you need a worksheet qualifier such as `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("C40-1").Range("A2:H54572")`  You should really declare and use a worksheet-type variable and set it to that sheet though, so you don't have to keep typing `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("C40-1")` throughout your code.

Comment: Key should only represent a single column

Comment: Hi @Tim. Thank you for your reply. So the scope here is that I am not familiar with coding sorting from scratch, so I used the record function and am now trying to make things dynamic. Your suggestion of declaring and setting wb and ws is exactly what I originally did. Then I was getting "object doesn't support method error" when I substituted it into the recorded code. Since code is running from the active sheet I just let that issue go because I can at least use a variable for the sheet name without error.  E.g. `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(myVar) ` 
But then I started getting above problem

Answer (score 0):

Following from comments above:

```vb
Sub reorder()

    Dim LR As Long, ws As Worksheet, thisRange As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("C40-1")
    LR = 54572 
    
    thisRange = "A2:H" & LR
    
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        'Key should be only a single column...
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range(thisRange).Columns(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange ws.Range(thisRange)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim. Thank you for your reply. So the scope here is that I am not familiar with coding sorting from scratch, so I used the record function and am trying to make things dynamic. Your suggestion of declaring things is exactly what I originally did.

Comment: Does it work for you though?  I don't know how to write a sort from scratch either - I always start with recorded code and clean it up.